# JQuery: Alternative to each() for conditional check against selected checkbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-readability

1) Checkboxes has five values: GRA, RRA, FRA, MRA, CHDA

2) Checkbox class Name is oops. Common for all 5.

3) We shall throw an exception if FRA, MRA, CHDA value is not selected

4) Following is snippet i am using to achieve this:

```
var availability = false;

$(".oops:checked").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() === 'FRA' || $(this).val() === 'MRA' || $(this).val() === 'CHDA') {
        availability = true;
    }
});

if (!availability) {
    errors.push('There is no selected among FRA MRA CHRA');            
}
```

Do we have other better approach to handle this instead of using three or operators and check it in each() function?

Comment: create array for that and than check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a array data structure for all the allowed values for the checkbox and check the selected values against them:

```
var availability = false;
var alloweValues = ['FRA', 'MRA', 'CHDA']; 
$(".oops:checked").each(function() {
    if(alloweValues.includes($(this).val())) {
      availability = true;
    }
});
if (!availability) {
    errors.push('There is no selected among FRA MRA CHRA');            
}
```

You can further refactor your code to:

```
var availability = false;
var alloweValues = ['FRA', 'MRA', 'CHDA']; 
$(".oops:checked").each(function() {
    availability = alloweValues.includes($(this).val());
});
if (!availability) {
    errors.push('There is no selected among FRA MRA CHRA');            
}
```

You can also replace `includes()` with `indexOf()` like

```
alloweValues.indexOf($(this).val()) !== -1
```

As, `includes()` do not work in IE browser.

Comment: Thanks. I like that. You may share more inputs. Also we need to declare these constants somehow -> 'FRA', 'MRA', 'CHDA' to check it.

Will Mark it as answer. :)

Comment: @fatherazrael glad to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Create an array to store each checked value like follows:

```
var checkvalues=[];
 $(".oops:checked").each(function(){
        checkvalues.push($(this).val());
    });
```

after that you can use `includes()` method to check like above code.